# MSVC: inspecting static libraries (fixing unresolved external symbols)

Tags: visual-c++, linker, lnk2019

I wanted to ask what tools and techniques you use to fix linker errors in MSVC. My problem is, that I link an executable against a self built static lib and I get a lot of unresolved external symbols (LNK2019). I've tried building my libs with different calling conventions but I didn't succeed.

I want to inspect that lib file (it's a debug build) and see what functions are made available by that lib to maybe find the cause of the linker error.

I'd appreciate any suggestions how to systematically debug missing external symbols.

thanks,
Norbert

Answer (score 1):

Usually these are due to compiler switches or options being different between multiple pieces. Make sure you use the same compiler switch for code generation in all of them: especially the runtime libraries need to be the same (under C/C++ in Runtime Library -- Multi Threaded (/MT) (static) or Multi Threaded DLL (/MD)). This indicates that you want to statically link agains the Microsoft runtime or not.